# How to create a video from a series of images

Tags: image-processing, video-conversion

I have a series of 20 .tif images. I want to create an .avi video from them but I want each image to be shown for 4-5 seconds. I tried `ffmpeg` but I cannot find a way to make them be shown for this specific time. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-framerate` option of `ffmpeg` to control this. It's possible to use a fractional value for this setting. Using `-framerate 1/5` will show all frames for 5 seconds, `-framerate 1/4` will show them for 4 seconds.

I you require varying duration for each frame, it is necessary to alter the overall framerate, and duplicate these frames. You could set the framerate to 1, which would be 1 second increments, then have a number of copies of each frame which matches the desired duration in seconds. It may be possible to use soft-links rather than full copies of files to avoid using excessive disk space.